# Как удалить стандартные ярлыки из Проводника?

Tags: windows

Эти ярлыки мешают мне работать с другими файлами, при чём Control Panel на тулбаре продублирована. На рабочем столе я их уже отключил. Как можно удалить эти ярлыки из Проводника, через RegEdit?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: я хочу удалить эти ярлыки из проводника, не с экрана рабочего стола, на рабочем столе их уже нету, а в проводнике они остались.

Comment: Опишите проблему верхнего уровня, для чего вам это, может быть у нее будет более простое высокоуровневое решение.

Comment: Эти ярлыки также встречаются в тулбаре на панеле задач, где они тоже мешают работе с другими файлами, при чём Control Panel на тулбаре продублирована дважды https://i.imgur.com/5IM3f6U.jpg

Comment: что это за тулбар то вообще? откуда берется вообще эта панель ваша7

Comment: Пр. кн. мышки на Пенали Задач / Toolbar / Desktop

Comment: Ну так снимите галочку и не будет этой панели

Comment: Я наоборот пользуюсь этой панелью, и мне не нужны там ярлыки которых на рабочем столе нет. Также ярлыки есть в папке Desktop которых на рабочем столе нет.

Comment: подсказка - можно создать свою папку и поместить ее туда. И набросать тех ярлыков, которые нужны.

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит, мне нужна там работа с файлами динамически, переносить их туда из окна браузера, и удалять их по нажатию правой кнопкой мышки/удалить. Мне удалось найти другой ответ, создав новый тулбар с специальным путём %USERPROFILE%\Desktop